# How do i stack columns in Bootstrap 4 for mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to 2 columns stacked on desktop but on mobile I want the order switched the other way round.

```
<div class="row bottom-footer">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 order-2 order-sm-12">
      <span class="">text</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 order-1 order-col-md-6">
      <span class="">text</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want for mobile you see spans side by side?

Comment: Yes, I want the columns to switch order when it is col-sm

Comment: so why you use:`order-col-md-6` ??

Answer (score 3):

You only need to reorder the first column. Use **`order-last`** and **`order-sm-first`** to do so.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row bottom-footer">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 order-last order-sm-first">
    <span class="">text1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
    <span class="">text2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Since you use `col-md-6`, `col-lg-6` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `order-2 order-sm-1` and `order-1 order-sm-2` respectively on both divs

`order-1` and `order-2` will start applying from 0px to mobile width and `order-sm-*` will start applying after mobile screen widths.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row bottom-footer">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 order-2 order-sm-1">
    <span class="">text1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 order-1 order-sm-2">
    <span class="">text2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TomSpink Plese accept my answer if it worked for you so that iff someone visits this answer in future, he/she might know that this workedfor you :)

Comment: doesn't need all those classes, just in one div, see the other answer

Comment: Seen that answer already @dippas . Thanks :)